# I need some advice how to connect external database with my app and web page

Tags: android

Im creating an app in which users could browse from many sale offers with cars.
I would like to potential sellers could acces and enter data from web page, then save it to some external server/database.
My app only downlaods this data(pics, descriptions, etc) and show it in some way.
I am begginig programmer with half year experience in android, but ive never set up my own server, neither use external database in my previous apps.
I would like to ask you what is the best way to achive this goal. I will be greatefull for any adivices or materials which i could start from.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-making-remote-api-calls--mobile-17568

Comment: you need to come  up with a specific route and ask for advice, i know you are a beginner but if you can start somewhere from nowhere you will end up somewhere close to success..

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you thought your data layer, but depending on you can use a database object-oriented, which in my opinion is great for such applications. visit the https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide is very easy to use think will like. so of course it will not have the need to use a webservice if you choose to use parse.